# An M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data source different from those defined in the model

Tags: azure, ssas, tabular, azure-analysis-services

I have about 5 Web Service (API) calls I am using, and none of them are working for me...

4 of them are returning this error:

> An M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data
>   source different from those defined in the model.

But guess what, these very same Web Services work in Power BI desktop.

I am in VS working on an AAS Tabular model.

Please help - I think this is just a VS bug...

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem but with getting data from an SQL Server in an on-premise SSAS. We used `Sql.Database` function in M (PowerQuery) code.
We managed to solve this problem by declaring this SQL Database as a Data Source and then referencing this Data Source in the M code.

Comment: Your answer is only valid for SQL Server Databases, not valid for informix for example.