# SSMS: An M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data source different from those defined in the model

Tags: odbc, ssms, cube

I'm facing a problem trying to process my cube (1400) on SSMS. The cube consists of 2 existing cubes being combined. Every table that uses the following M-code is returning an error: **An M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data source different from those defined in the model**

```
"expression": [
              "let",
              "    Source = Odbc.Query(\"dsn=ODS_STG\", \"select#(tab)*#(lf)from#(tab)work_area_06.datamart_vx_dpm_pc_task#(lf)where#(tab)cast(left(cast(fk_snapshotdate as string),4) as bigint) >= year(current_timestamp())-1;\")",
              "in",
              "    Source"
            ]
```

Any help on tackling this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think this one kind of answers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199044/an-m-partition-uses-a-data-function-which-results-in-access-to-a-data-source-dif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the string to:

```
Source = Odbc.Query(\"dsn=ODS_STG\", \"select#(tab)*#(lf)from#(tab)work_area_06.datamart_vx_dpm_pc_task#(lf)where#(tab)cast(left(cast(fk_snapshotdate as string),4) as bigint) >= year(current_timestamp(**))-1\")",**
              "in",
              "    Source"
            ]
```